# Finite Subgroups of the Units of an Integral Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $U(R)$ be the multiplicative group of the units of $R$. Is it true that each finite subgroup of $U(R)$ is cyclic?

I do know that each finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a "field" is cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each integral domain $R$ can be embedded in a field $K$, and units in $R$ are units in $K$. So once we know each finite subgroup of the units in a field is cyclic, it follows that each finite subgroup of the units of an integral domain is cyclic.

Alternatively, you can check that a proof of the result about finite subgroups of the unit group of a field carries over to finite subgroups of the unit group of an integral domain.

If, for instance, a proof in the case of fields only needs the field property that polynomials of each degree $d$ over a field have at most $d$ roots in the field, then the proof will carry over directly to integral domains because you can prove directly that when $R$ is an integral domain, each polynomial in $R[x]$ of degree $d$ has at most $d$ roots in $R$.  (Yes, $R[x]$ is not a Euclidean domain when $R$ is not a field, but you can still do division with remainder by *monic* polynomials when $R$ is an integral domain, and in particular by $x - a$ for each $a \in R$, so having $a$ as a root corresponds to having $x-a$ as a factor.)